# Perl script to modify one file taking values from second file

Tags: perl, file-handling

I've written a Perl Script which processes two files, File 1 contains some text in which 'ABC' needs to be replaced with the list of values present in 2nd text file.

File1.txt :

```
Name     -> ABC

Record   -> Exists

Presence -> Existing_ABC
```

File2.txt :

```
John

Claude

Kepler

Shane

Austin
```

I want to replace 'ABC' from File1 with John then the original File1 should be taken again and 'ABC' should get replaced with Claude and merged with the first iteration and so on in the similar way till the last entry of the File2.
So, presently the script is giving the output for only one value 'John' it doesn't take other values from the list.

Final Output.txt file should be like:

```
Name     -> John

Record   -> Exists

Presence -> Existing_John


Name     -> Claude

Record   -> Exists

Presence -> Existing_Claude

.

.

.

.
.


(#till Austin)
```

Please find me the mistake in my script and Thanks in advance:->

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use warnings;

my @blockList   =  load_block_list();

my $rules_file  =  'File1.txt';

my $out_file    =  'out.txt';  

open( my $rules,  '<',  $rules_file  );

open( my $out,    '>',  $out_file  );

my $Orig_line;

my $new_line;

my $key;


foreach my $Element (@blockList) {

    while($Orig_line=<$rules>) {

        chomp($Orig_line);

        $new_line = $Orig_line;

        if($Orig_line =~ m/ABC/) {
            $new_line =~ s/ABC/$Element/;
        }

        print {$out} "$new_line\n";

    }
}

sub load_block_list
{
    my $block_list = "File2.txt";

    open(DAT, $block_list) || die("Could not open file $block_list!");
    my @lines=<DAT>;
    close(DAT);

    my @retVal = ();
    foreach my $line (@lines) {
        $line =~ s/[\r\n]+//g;
        push(@retVal,$line),
    }
    return @retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read `File1.txt` before iterating over `@blockList`.
Something like this:

```
...
my @template = load_template(); 
my @blockList = load_block_list();
...
foreach my $Element (@blockList) {
    foreach my $Orig_line (@template) {
...
```

`load_template` should be similar to `load_block_list`.